# I want to use All extracted values in a loop controller

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have written a regular expression inorder to get all the values. Now i have all the values. I want to use the extracted values in a sampler under a loop controller and every hit it has to pic dynamic value.

[This will have the dynamic values around 78](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5ify.png)

[I want to Iterate 78 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiT7S.png)

[Every hit this has to pic unique data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71c4c.png)

Please help me as i am stuck here to complete the script.

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable test element is [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

1. Given the following variables defined:

   [image]
2. Just add a ForEach Controller and configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to access each and every match as `${someVar}` where required

   [image]

   check out [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter/) article for example use case

---

If you want to keep the current setup with the Loop Controller - you can refer each and every variable using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) functions combination like:

```
${__V(_Webp_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot..I have used for each controller. which works fine.